# Article 'the' usage in noun + number

Tags: articles

Which is the correct one ?

1. How can I get to the gate D32 ?
2. How can I get to gate D32 ?

Comment: When the noun is qualified, the definite article may not be needed. "How can I get to the gate?" (there's only one gate, or you want to get to any gate); "How can I get to gate D32?" (a particular gate, so no "*the*"). HTH.

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris: Suppose you were in an airport, how would you ask for a way to a particular gate you need to?

Comment: They are both *correct*.

Comment: "...how would you ask for a way to a particular gate...?"  As I said, no definite article: "How can I get to gate D32?" HTH.

Comment: @JasonBassford No. See my comments. Good Luck.